Flat Module from book of NS Gopala Krishnan
I was reading flat modules from book by NS Gopalakrishnan. In starting of faithfully flat algebra the below is written
Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra, $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules. Then homomorphism
$\phi_M : A⊗_{R}$ Hom$_{R}(M,N) \to $ Hom$_A ( A⊗_{R} M ,  A⊗_{R} N)$ is defined by
$\phi_M(a ⊗ f) = g_{a ⊗f}$
where $g_{a⊗ f}  (b ⊗ m )= ab ⊗ f(m) $.
They said  $\phi_M$ is an isomorphism if $M = R$.
I face difficulties in proving $\phi_R$ is bijective.
I know that if $M=R$ then $A ⊗_{R} M = A$  ,  $A ⊗_{R} N = A$. But then I could not proceed further.

Hint: prove that, $\text{Hom}_R(R,M) =R$, where $M$ is an $R$ module.

If $M=R$, then we have the isomorphism, $$\text{Hom}_R(M, N)=\text{Hom}_R(R, N)\simeq N\text{ and}\\
A⊗_{R} M=A⊗_{R} R\simeq A.$$
So we get the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A\otimes_R\text{Hom}_R(M, N) @>{\phi_M}>> \text{Hom}_A(A⊗_{R} M,  A⊗_{R}N)\\
@V{\simeq}VV @VV{\simeq}V\\
A\otimes_RN @>{a\otimes_Rn\mapsto\varphi_{a\otimes_Rn}}>> \text{Hom}_A(A,  A⊗_{R}N)
\end{CD}
Here $\varphi_{a\otimes_Rn}:A\to A\otimes_RN$ defined by $\varphi_{a\otimes_Rn}(b)=ab\otimes_Rn$ for all $b\in A$.
Now note that the bottom row and the two columns of the diagram are isomorphism. This gives $\phi_M$ is an isomorphism.
